# How to change the standard font in laravel? fontsquirrel

Tags: css, fonts, laravel-blade

I'm pretty new at Laravel 5.8 and I would like to change the whole fonts for 'Roboto Slab' from 'www.fontsquirrel.com'.

I have tried by downloading and adding it as a style in my app.blade

However as expected it doesn't work and I'm pretty sure this is not the right way to change the whole font in my project as well.

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: RobotoSlab;
    src: url('{{ URL::asset('public/assets/fonts/roboto-slab/RobotoSlab-Light.ttf') }}')format(‘truetype’);
} 

 p{
    font-family: RobotoSlab;        
}
```

I've used this code in order to try if the font worked. no results

Comment: Why don't you use the [Google font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Slab) ?

Comment: I know it would be easier, the reason why I'm trying to change it is in order to learn more. Just curious.

Comment: oh... ok! Well the `asset` function takes as root the `public` folder so, try removing the `public` segment

Comment: Oh Thank you, it worked .